# Some examples of order dependent double integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Can anybody give some two-three examples of the limiations of Fubini's theorem where switching the order of integration yeilds different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very well known result:

- $$\int_{\text{x}=0}^1\left\{\int_{\text{y}=0}^1\frac{\text{x}^2-\text{y}^2}{\left(\text{x}^2+\text{y}^2\right)^2}\space\text{d}\text{y}\right\}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+\text{x}^2}\space\text{d}\text{x}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
- $$\int_{\text{y}=0}^1\left\{\int_{\text{x}=0}^1\frac{\text{x}^2-\text{y}^2}{\left(\text{x}^2+\text{y}^2\right)^2}\space\text{d}\text{x}\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+\text{y}^2}\space\text{d}\text{y}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
- $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\left|\frac{\text{x}^2-\text{y}^2}{\left(\text{x}^2+\text{y}^2\right)^2}\right|\space\text{d}\text{y}\space\text{d}\text{x}\to\infty$$

See [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions).